# Why converting a .py file to a .exe file with an already converted executable file doesn't work?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, executable

I have my `convert.py` file that converts `myFile.py` to `myFile.exe`, and that's working. But when I convert `convert.py` to `convert.exe` it won't convert `myFile.py` anymore.

All of these files are inside of one folder:

[image]

***`convert.py`:***

```py
import PyInstaller.__main__
PyInstaller.__main__.run([os.path.abspath("myFile.py"), '--noconfirm', '--onefile', '--console', f'--icon={os.path.abspath("icon.ico")}', "--name", "myFile"])
```

***`myFile.py`:***

```py
print("Hello World!")
while True:
    continue
```

When running `convert.exe` 2 folders should be created: `build` and `dist`, `myFile.exe` should be created inside of `dist`, but [here's a video of what's happening](https://vimeo.com/740035794), and [here's a video of what should be happening](https://vimeo.com/740037219).

Comment: run `convert.exe` in an already open command prompt and post the output.

Comment: @Harsh I just tried and it's the exact same thing...

Comment: I won't create an account on Vimeo to watch your video...

Comment: the behavior you want is not as simple as you think, let me explain it slowly, when you run it using your IDE , it will be using a certain python interpreter inside a certain environment, both the interpreter and the environment change when you compile a file to an executable, the executable don't just have to "run pyinstaller" it has to set up the environment correctly and has to connect to a different python interpreter that it going to execute pyinstaller ... this is not as straight forward as you may think, nor portable to another computer, just substitute the executable with a .bat file.

Comment: it's not impossible to do, it just needs someone to write an entire library that is going to do all the required wiring at runtime, which is extensive, and there are easier approaches to compiling applications at runtime, for applications that actually require compiling things at runtime, which are usually very specific.

Answer (score 3):

### Your problem

The problems at this point are the file locations.

When you run the `convert.py` it looks for the file `myFile.py`. This is found in the same directory and the path is forwarded to pyinstaller. `myfile.exe` is created and everything is fine.

When you create `convert.exe` via pyinstaller as a one-file distribution and then run it, there are **different** path locations:

(a) path to the `convert.exe`

(b) path where `convert.exe` is executed

When you start `convert.exe` (in path (a) ) the content is extracted to a temporary directory and executed there (path (b) ). As in this path (b) no file `myFile.py` exists this will not work.

### Possible solutions:

#### one-dir distribution

create a one-dir distribution of your `convert.py`. To avoid always searching for the *.exe in the distribution directory create a batch-file at the parent directory which will step in the subfolder and executes the *.exe for you. Also, change the search path of `myfile.py` to `../myfile.py` in your code, so that it looks in the parent directory of the *.exe (the same path as the batch-file)

#### user input

for this solution you can use a one-file distribution of your `convert.py`. While executing the `convert.exe` just ask the user for the absolute path of the file which should be converted

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you meant by the "one-dir distribution", if u meant replacing `onefile` with `onedir` in the command it would create a hole folder that the .exe is dependent to, it can't work without it, and I do not want to have this issue. And a user input isn't a possible solution cause the cause the converting thing is just a small part of a bigger program where at the end of the execution a python script is created and then **should** be converted a an executable automatically, with any user interaction.

Comment: You interpreted correctly what I meant with ```onedir```, yes. Sorry this did not work for you. You said you auto-create a python script which then should be converted. Is it perhaps possible to put the created script to the same folder everytime, then you can use an absolute path to this folder in your ```convert.exe```. sounds horrible but in this specific case perhaps helps

Answer (score 1):

1. Try running a command from CMD Administrative
2. Use the full path when calling the pyinstaller
3. Uninstall pyinstaller, and install it again

command for

```
pyinstaller ./myFile.py --onefile --icon=icon.ico --noconsole --clean -D -F
```

If none of the above works, then try using py2exe. It is similar to pyinstaller [here](https://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial) is the guide.

Comment: 1. is not a solution cause the program should do that on its own without the user's interaction for the conversion. 

2. the path isn't the problem cause os.path.abspath("myFile.py") is the full path (os.path.abspath() adds the rest of the path to the "myFile.py"). 

3. I want this to work on any computer, with or without python installed (so no pyinstaller installed too), that's why I want convert.py to be an executable.